# querying sqlite using string as where condition

Tags: android

why does when i use a string as a where condition in my database, my program just force close. though it is working fine if i use number as a query condition. please help me, thanks

```
public ArrayList<Contact> getAvailableList() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Contact> results = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_NAME, KEY_NUMBER, KEY_STATUS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_STATUS +"=available" , null, null, null, KEY_NAME);
    String sName = "";
    String sNum = "";
    String status = "";
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iNumber = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NUMBER);
    int iStatus = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STATUS);
    Contact contact;
    for(c.moveToFirst(); ! c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
    {
        contact = new Contact();
        sName += c.getString(iName);
        sNum += c.getString(iNumber);
        status += c.getString(iStatus);
        contact.setName(sName);
        //contact.setPhoneNumber(sNum);
        contact.setPhoneNumber("0".concat(sNum));
        contact.setStatus(status);
        results.add(contact);
        sName = "";
        sNum = "";
        status = "";
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap strings in SQL with quotes, like this:

```
//                                                       Add these  v         v
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_STATUS +"='available'", 
        null, null, null, KEY_NAME);
```

Or if you want to use dynamic data, you should use the `selectionArgs` parameter:

```
String status = "available";
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_STATUS +"=?", 
        new String[] {status}, null, null, KEY_NAME);
```

This approach simplifies keeping track of matching quotes in complex Java/SQL Strings, more importantly it protect you from SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `' '` around `available`

```
  Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_STATUS +"='available'" , null, null, null, KEY_NAME);
```